# How to send multiple emails in php when a selection is given a value?

Tags: php, html

I want to add multiple recipients in my php code but every time I do my sight crashes or only goes to the first email.

I've tried adding it the following ways:

```
 'em1' => ' time@maryanndul.com', 'admin@maryanndul.com',

and

 'em1' => ' time@maryanndul.com , admin@maryanndul.com',
```

HTML form:

```
<select type="text" name="recipents" id ="recipients"> 
<option value="em1" selected="default">Time & Attendance
</option>
<option value="em2">Parking Systems
</option>
<option value="em3">Video Surveillance
</option>
<option value="em4">Access Control
</option>

</select>
```

php code:

```
$email_to = (empty($_POST['recipents'])) ? 'default' : $_POST['recipents'];


$email_addresses = array (
  'em1' => ' time@maryanndul.com',
  'em2' => 'parking@maryanndul.com',
  'em3' => 'video@maryanndul.com',
  'em4'=>'access@maryanndul.com', 
  'default' => 'admin@maryanndul.com'
   );

if(!array_key_exists($email_to, $email_addresses)) {
   $email_to = $email_addresses['default'];}
   else{
    $email_to = $email_addresses[$email_to];
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _"crashes"_?

Comment: Why don't you `$email_to = impode(",",$email_addresses;` and remove that first space on em1

Comment: Comma delimited email addresses will work when sending to multiple recipients.  I think we'll need more info on what you mean by "crashes".

Comment: What I mean is that the sight crashes and says that this page isn't working maryanndul.com is currently unable to handle this request.

Comment: I tried $email_to = impode(",",$email_addresses); and it also crashes with the same message. The reason way I'm doing it this way is that it is part of a form that the user selects what department they want to reach with their request for contact.